# ReCaptcha and php_self

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

I have a form set up that works very well.  I'm trying to add recaptcha to it but am not sure where to put the server-side validation at since my form posts it to php_self.
Code just in case:

```
   <form id='register' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
```

which goes here

```
function GetSelfScript()
{
    return htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

}
```

Comment: in the same file? i'm not sure what you are a asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `PHP_SELF` is included in a PHP file, the file is pointing at itself. For example, in `/file.php`, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` refers to `/file.php`. Therefore, you should add reCAPTCHA validation to whichever file contains the `PHP_SELF` reference.

Comment: Oh, okay I got it now. Thanks Jack!

Comment: @KurtisOrr No problem, would you mind marking my answer correct? Thanks!

Comment: There you go!
I need more points so I can give you a thumbs up!